# Updating multiple items in nested array when condition matched

Tags: mongodb

I started learning MongoDB a few days ago and trying to wrap my head around **update** operator.

Here's the document structure I have:

```
db.records.insertMany([
  {
    name: 'first',
    subrecords: [
      { id: 1, isToBeUpdated: 0, value: 1 },
      { id: 2, isToBeUpdated: 0, value: 2 },
      { id: 3, isToBeUpdated: 0, value: 3 },
      { id: 4, isToBeUpdated: 1, value: 4 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    subrecords: [
      { id: 22, isToBeUpdated: 1, value: 5 },
      { id: 23, isToBeUpdated: 0, value: 6 },
      { id: 24, isToBeUpdated: 1, value: 7 },
      { id: 25, isToBeUpdated: 0, value: 8 }
    ]
  }
])
```

I'm writing a command that is supposed to update `subrecords`.

My intent is to use `isToBeUpdated` flag — if it is set to `1` we update the value field, e.g. multiplying it by 10. **We ignore items with** `isToBeUpdated` **being** `0`.

Here's the command I've composed:

```
db.records.update(
  { 'subrecords.isToBeUpdated': 1 },
  { '$mul': { 'subrecords.$.value': 10 } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

I expect to get the following items of `subrecords` array updated like this:

```
1. { id: 4, isToBeUpdated: 1, value: 40 }
2. { id: 22, isToBeUpdated: 1, value: 50 }
3. { id: 24, isToBeUpdated: 1, value: 70 }
```

BUT it just updates 2 records, instead of 3. The following record is not updated:

```
3. { id: 24, isToBeUpdated: 1, value: 70 }
```

**It is the second item with** `isToBeUpdated` **being** `1` **located in the second document's** `subrecords` **collection** — seems like the query only updates **the first matching item of subrecords array in any document. And ignores other records that are subsequent to first.**

I tried tweaking my command adding `[]` to `$` (positional operator):

```
... { '$mul': { 'subrecords.$[].value': 10 } }, ...
```

But in this case literally every single item in subrecords array of any document gets affected.

---

**Anyone knows how to write a command which loops through all records and updates each item of the nested** `subrecords` **array with** `isToBeUpdated` **field being set to** `1`?

---

Also, am I right in thinking

1. that `{ multi: true }` implies that ALL record documents in `records` collection will be affected?
2. that `{ 'subrecords.isToBeUpdated': 1 }` (query part) literally means that WE ONLY UPDATE subrecords ARRAY WHEN A DOCUMENT HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN subrecords ARRAY WITH `isToBeUpdated` FIELD BEING SET TO `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The workaround turns out to be `arrayFilters`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array

> The $[<identifier>] operator facilitates updates to arrays that contain embedded documents. To access the fields in the embedded documents, use the dot notation on the $[<identifier>].

```
db.records.update(
  {},
  { '$mul': { 'subrecords.$[elem].value': 10 } },
  {
    multi: true,
    arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.isToBeUpdated': 1 }]
  }
)
```

### Solved!