# How to update every matching array element in a collection?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have the following structure for my "Matches" collection and I need to go through all 290 records and update the playerName value from "GYLNNALDINHO" to "GLYNNALDINHO". This player appears in 77 of the 290 records.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6041690d9105df684c0c16c3"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-03-04T23:10:27.000Z"),
    "game" : 290,
    "players" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6041690d9105df684c0c16c6"),
            "playerName" : "GYLNNALDINHO",
            "playerGoals" : 0,
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6041690d9105df684c0c16c7"),
            "playerName" : "GLYNNALDO",
            "playerGoals" : 0,
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the script in robo3t I am running:

```
db.getCollection('matches').find({})
    .forEach(match => {
        match.players.forEach(player => {
            if(player.playerName === "GYLNNALDINHO") {
                    player.playerName = "GLYNNALDINHO";
                    }
            })

        db.getCollection('matches').save(match);
});
```

I get the following result but when I check the tables again it does not update all values. I'm not sure if it actually updates any. Is there something wrong with the above code?

```
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 48ms
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 48ms
Updated 0 record(s) in 48ms
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 48ms
Updated 0 record(s) in 50ms
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating multiple items in nested array when condition matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498904/updating-multiple-items-in-nested-array-when-condition-matched)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't any issue with the code the issue was with Robo 3T's shell timeout. It needed increasing from 15 seconds to 30.